# How to set an image to temporarily appear on the screen?

Tags: image, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm new in typescript, I would like to know how to set an image to appear on the screen for 5 seconds and then disappear. Which logic should I use in TS? I use Ionic v3. I would like to see an example.

html:

```
<img id="imageID"  src="assets/img/setas.png">
```

Comment: use setTimeout()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `hidden`

### home.html

```
<ion-content>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" [hidden]="isImageHidden"/>
</ion-content>
```

### home.ts

```
export class HomePage 
{
    isImageHidden = false;
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public alertCtrl:AlertController) 
    {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            this.isImageHidden = true;
        },5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.